# sort/select the unique and the latest data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to take the most relevant value from my data here. I figured out to take the oldest and the most recent dates using max and min function in pandas but i couldn't find the fix to the rest. I'm trying to take one unqiue company and product from my data set and get the rest of their data based on these points. If anyone could tell me the toolsets used in python to address such issues that will be great or guidance on how such issues are addressed in python, that would be very helpful.

- for security_level, superservere>severe > moderate > material > minor
- for rating, take true if we see the same company and product got both true and flase
- for rating_level, critical > high > medium > low
- for first_level, the oldest date and for last_release, the most recent date
- score, the highest score amongst the same prodcut and company

| company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | mobile | minor | TRUE | critical | 04/11/2020 | 03/17/2020 | 0.5 |
| google | os | moderate | FALSE | medium | 09/05/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 0.009 |
| google | os | minor | FALSE | low | 09/04/2019 | 05/11/2020 | 19 |
| google | tv | severe | TRUE | high | 08/11/2020 | 03/04/2021 |  |
| google | mobile | supersevere | FALSE | medium | 04/06/2015 | 08/19/2020 | 2.4 |
| google | mobile | minor | FALSE | high | 08/08/2019 | 08/19/2020 | 1.3 |
| apple | iphone | minor | TRUE | low | 02/03/2020 | 10/13/2020 | 3 |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 01/21/2018 | 03/04/2021 | 6 |
| apple | iwatch | material | FALSE | low | 04/11/2015 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 10/20/2020 | 03/19/2021 | 5 |
| dell | laptop | minor | FALSE | low | 01/05/2021 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Output:

| company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | mobile | supersevere | TRUE | critical | 04/06/2015 | 08/19/2020 | 2.4 |
| google | os | moderate | FALSE | medium | 09/04/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 19 |
| google | tv | severe | TRUE | high | 08/11/2020 | 03/04/2021 |  |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 01/21/2018 | 03/19/2021 | 6 |
| apple | iwatch | material | FALSE | low | 04/11/2015 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| dell | laptop | minor | FALSE | low | 01/05/2021 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `dtype` of `first_release` and `last_release` columns to `datetime`

```
df['last_release']  = pd.to_datetime(df['last_release'])
df['first_release'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_release'])
```

Convert the columns `security_level` and `rating_level` to `ordered` `categorical` type

```
df['rating_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['rating_level'], ['low', 'medium', 'high', 'critical'], ordered=True)
df['security_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['security_level'], ['minor', 'material', 'moderate', 'severe', 'supersevere'], ordered=True)
```

`Group` the dataframe on columns `company` and `product` and aggregate the remaining columns with the corresponding aggregation functions specified in `agg_dict`

```
agg_dict = {'security_level': 'max', 'rating': 'max', 'rating_level': 'max',
            'first_release': 'min', 'last_release': 'max', 'score': 'max'}
            
out = df.groupby(['company', 'product'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(agg_dict)
```

Result

```
>>> out

  company product security_level  rating rating_level first_release last_release  score
0  google  mobile    supersevere    True     critical    2015-04-06   2020-08-19    2.4
1  google      os       moderate   False       medium    2019-09-04   2021-03-20   19.0
2  google      tv         severe    True         high    2020-08-11   2021-03-04    NaN
3   apple  iphone       material    True       medium    2018-01-21   2021-03-19    6.0
4   apple  iwatch       material   False          low    2015-04-11   2020-08-13    8.0
5    dell  laptop          minor   False          low    2021-01-05   2021-03-20    1.0
```

Comment: How is the dictionary (agg_dict) able to distinguish or aid the sort, to me the agg_dict looks like a bunch of strings in a dictionary format? Could you please explain that piece

Comment: `agg_dict` is a mapping from `column name` to the corresponding aggregation functions like `max` which selects the max value per group in the column on which it is applied.

Comment: {'id': 'max' } does this indicate that we are going for the maximum value amongst the ids, i was under the impression that dictionaries don't recognize max/min keywords, they treat everything as strings was my assumption.

Comment: You are correct dictionary doesn't recognize these keywords, for dictionary these are just strings but when you pass this dictionary to `agg` method of pandas groupby object then pandas will recognize these special names as aggregation functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is as your question states,  sort, then select first row of each group.  You have defined sorting by categories

```
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['google', 'google', 'google', 'google', 'google', 'google', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'dell'], 
              'product': ['mobile', 'os', 'os', 'tv', 'mobile', 'mobile', 'iphone', 'iphone', 'iwatch', 'iphone', 'laptop'], 
              'security_level': ['minor', 'moderate', 'minor', 'severe', 'supersevere', 'minor', 'minor', 'material', 'material', 'material', 'minor'], 
              'rating': [True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True, False, True, False], 
              'rating_level': ['critical', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'medium', 'low'], 
              'first_release': ['04/11/2020', '09/05/2019', '09/04/2019', '08/11/2020', '04/06/2015', '08/08/2019', '02/03/2020', '01/21/2018', '04/11/2015', '10/20/2020', '01/05/2021'], 
              'last_release': ['03/17/2020', '03/20/2021', '05/11/2020', '03/04/2021', '08/19/2020', '08/19/2020', '10/13/2020', '03/04/2021', '08/13/2020', '03/19/2021', '03/20/2021'], 
              'score': [0.5, 0.009, 19.0, nan, 2.4, 1.3, 3.0, 6.0, 8.0, 5.0, 1.0]})

# fix data types of columns.  Categoricals for sort orders
df.first_release = pd.to_datetime(df.first_release)
df.last_release = pd.to_datetime(df.last_release)
df.security_level = pd.Categorical(df.security_level, ['supersevere','severe','material','moderate','minor'], ordered=True)
df.rating_level = pd.Categorical(df.rating_level, ['critical', 'high', 'medium', 'low', ], ordered=True)

dfs = df.sort_values(['company', 'product', 'security_level', 'rating', 'rating_level','first_release', 'last_release'],
              ascending=[1,1,1,0,1,0,1])
```

#### after sorting using all rules

|  | company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | apple | iphone | material | True | medium | 2020-10-20 00:00:00 | 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 7 | apple | iphone | material | True | medium | 2018-01-21 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 00:00:00 | 6 |
| 6 | apple | iphone | minor | True | low | 2020-02-03 00:00:00 | 2020-10-13 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 8 | apple | iwatch | material | False | low | 2015-04-11 00:00:00 | 2020-08-13 00:00:00 | 8 |
| 10 | dell | laptop | minor | False | low | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 2021-03-20 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 4 | google | mobile | supersevere | False | medium | 2015-04-06 00:00:00 | 2020-08-19 00:00:00 | 2.4 |
| 0 | google | mobile | minor | True | critical | 2020-04-11 00:00:00 | 2020-03-17 00:00:00 | 0.5 |
| 5 | google | mobile | minor | False | high | 2019-08-08 00:00:00 | 2020-08-19 00:00:00 | 1.3 |
| 1 | google | os | moderate | False | medium | 2019-09-05 00:00:00 | 2021-03-20 00:00:00 | 0.009 |
| 2 | google | os | minor | False | low | 2019-09-04 00:00:00 | 2020-05-11 00:00:00 | 19 |
| 3 | google | tv | severe | True | high | 2020-08-11 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 00:00:00 | nan |
|  | company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |

#### finally just take `first()`

```
dfs.groupby(["company","product"],as_index=False).first()
```

|  | company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | iphone | material | True | medium | 2020-10-20 00:00:00 | 2021-03-19 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 1 | apple | iwatch | material | False | low | 2015-04-11 00:00:00 | 2020-08-13 00:00:00 | 8 |
| 2 | dell | laptop | minor | False | low | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 2021-03-20 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 3 | google | mobile | supersevere | False | medium | 2015-04-06 00:00:00 | 2020-08-19 00:00:00 | 2.4 |
| 4 | google | os | moderate | False | medium | 2019-09-05 00:00:00 | 2021-03-20 00:00:00 | 0.009 |
| 5 | google | tv | severe | True | high | 2020-08-11 00:00:00 | 2021-03-04 00:00:00 | nan |

Comment: thanks for the response! but what if my data set more data other than 'google' or 'apple'. I'm looking for a generic solution that can be used irrespective of the company or product names

Comment: you are repeatedly asking same question - not a good idea on SO.  I've updated,  you sort order of categorically defined data is now included