# select unique and most relevant data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to take the the unique company and product name from my df and filter the rest of the values based on

- security_level:pick up the most relevant one **superservere>severe > moderate > material > minor**, if higher not available then the second most hottest one
- rating, take true if there exists true and false for the product
- rating_level: pick the most higher one (**critical > high > medium > low**), if higher not available then the second most hottest one
- for first_level, the oldest date and for last_release, the most recent date
- score, the highest score amongst the same product and company

| company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | mobile | minor | TRUE | critical | 04/11/2020 | 03/17/2020 | 0.5 |
| google | os | moderate | FALSE | medium | 09/05/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 0.009 |
| google | os | minor | FALSE | low | 09/04/2019 | 05/11/2020 | 19 |
| google | tv | severe | TRUE | high | 08/11/2020 | 03/04/2021 |  |
| google | mobile | supersevere | FALSE | medium | 04/06/2015 | 08/19/2020 | 2.4 |
| google | mobile | minor | FALSE | high | 08/08/2019 | 08/19/2020 | 1.3 |
| apple | iphone | minor | TRUE | low | 02/03/2020 | 10/13/2020 | 3 |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 01/21/2018 | 03/04/2021 | 6 |
| apple | iwatch | material | FALSE | low | 04/11/2015 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 10/20/2020 | 03/19/2021 | 5 |
| dell | laptop | minor | FALSE | low | 01/05/2021 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Output:

| company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | mobile | supersevere | TRUE | critical | 04/06/2015 | 08/19/2020 | 2.4 |
| google | os | moderate | FALSE | medium | 09/04/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 19 |
| google | tv | severe | TRUE | high | 08/11/2020 | 03/04/2021 |  |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 01/21/2018 | 03/19/2021 | 6 |
| apple | iwatch | material | FALSE | low | 04/11/2015 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| dell | laptop | minor | FALSE | low | 01/05/2021 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Comment: I think you have asked a similar question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752065/sort-select-the-unique-and-the-latest-data ?

Comment: that's right! I'm brand new to this practise so i'm unaware of the rules here. Is it okay to have multiple discussions on the same thread here

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Generally it is not advisable to open multiple threads related to same  question..I'm going to mark this as an duplicate of the original question..and i will try to answer your question there.

Comment: thank you very much. I highly appreciate your generosity